# Ensure certain default sort order in MySql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a large MySql table with over 11 million rows. This is just a huge data set and my task is to be able to analyze the dataset based on certain rules.

Each row belongs to a certain `category`. There are 2 million different categories. I want to get all rows for a category and perform operations on that.

So currently, I do the following:

1. Select distinct categories from the table.
2. for each category : Select fields from table WHERE `category`=category

Even though my `category` column is indexed, it takes a really long time to execute `Step 2`. This is mainly because of the huge data set.

Alternatively, I can use GROUP BY clause, however I am not sure if it will be as fast since GROUP BY on such a huge dataset may be expensive, especially when considering that I will be running my analysis several times on parts of the dataset. A way to permanently ensure a sorted table would be useful.

Therefore as an alternative, I can speed up my queries if only my table is pre-sorted by `category`. Now I can just read the table row by row and perform the same operations in a much faster time, as all rows of one `category` will be fetched consecutively.

As the dataset (MySql table) is fixed and no update, delete, insert operations will be performed on it. I want to be able to ensure a way to maintain a default sort order by `category`. Can anyone suggest a trick to ensure the default sort order of the rows.

Maybe read all rows and rewrite them to a new table or add a new primary key which ensures this order?

Comment: Please show the table definition and query.

Comment: An index effectively *is* a "pre-sort".

Comment: Your table's clustered index is the nearest concept to a presorted table order. MySQL is a bit more limited than other DBMS's in how you can define these: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: Did you look into partitioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Even though my category column is indexed

Indexed by a **secondary** index? If so, you can encounter the following performance problems:

- InnoDB tables are always [clustered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) and the secondary index in clustered table can require a **double-lookup** (see the "Disadvantages of clustering" in [this article](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)).
- Indexed rows can be scattered all over the place (index can have bad [clustering factor](http://oracle-online-help.blogspot.com/2006/11/clustering-factor_28.html) - the link is for Oracle but the principle is the same). If so, an index **range** scan (such as `WHERE category = whatever`) can end-up loading many table pages, even though the index is actually used and only a small subset of rows is actually selected. This can destroy the range scan performance.

---

In alternative to the secondary index, consider using a natural primary key, which in InnoDB tables also acts as a clustering key. The primary/clustering key such as `{category, no}` will keep the rows of the same category physically close together, making both of your queries (and especially the second one) maximally efficient.

OTOH, if you want to keep the secondary index, consider [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) all the fields that you query, so the primary B-Tree doesn't have to be touched at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I just wish to find out if there is a way to 'pre-sort' so that it can be ensured that a simple select statement would return rows grouped by category. (I dont want to explicitly do this in my application layer)

Comment: @AmulyaKhare Did you actually follow the links I have provided? Clustering is exactly the "pre-sorting" you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one step regardless of indexing by doing something like (pseudo code):

```
Declare @LastCategory int = Null
Declare @Category int

For Each Row In
Select
  @Category = Category,
  ...
From
  Table
Order By 
  Category

  If @LastCategory Is Null Or @LastCategory != @Category
    Do any "New Category Steps"
    Set @LastCategory = @Category
  End
  Process Row

End For
```

With the index on category I'd expect this to perform OK. Your performance issues may be down to what you are doing when processing each row.

Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e53c98/1